# Why @each makes template rerender?

Tags: ember.js

```
Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.1
Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3
jQuery.VERSION : 1.8.2
```

here is a part of my model:

```
first_three: function() {
    var staples = this.get('staples');
    var data = staples.slice(0,3));
    return data;
    }.property('staples.@each.isLoaded')
```

I use it in a template:

```
{{#each staple in album.first_three}}
    {{#linkTo staples.details staple}}
        <img {{bindAttr src="staple.object.image_pict"}}>
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

as a result, I've got

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_OBJECT_ERR: Parameter is not an object
```

and

```
Error: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_OBJECT_ERR is a jQuery issue. Ember is dependent on jQuery in the Views. I had a similar issue where my each loop was building HTML tags that didn't exist (i.e. I forgot to add '>' on a tag). Is your loop kicking out any iteration at all? That would be a good place to start.